# Simple way of performing Matrix Factorization with tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, recommendation-engine, matrix-factorization

I've been searching on how to perform matrix factorization for this very simple and basic case that I will show, but didn't find anything. I only found complex and long solutions, so I will present what I want to solve:

```
U x V = A
```

I would just like to know how to solve this equation in Tensorflow 2, being **A** a known sparse matrix, and **U** and **V** two random initialized matrices. So I would like to find U and V, so that their multiplication is approximately equal to A.

For example, having these variables:

```
# I use this function to build a toy dataset for the sparse matrix
def build_rating_sparse_tensor(ratings):

  indices = ratings[['U_num', 'V_num']].values 

  values = ratings['rating'].values

  return tf.SparseTensor(
                indices=indices,
                values=values,
                dense_shape=[ratings.U_num.max()+1, ratings.V_num.max()+1])

# here I create what will be the matrix A
ratings = (pd.DataFrame({'U_num': list(range(0,10_000))*30,
                        'V_num': list(range(0,60_000))*5,
                        'rating': np.random.randint(6, size=300_000)})
                       .sample(1000)
                       .drop_duplicates(subset=['U_num','V_num'])
                       .sort_values(['U_num','V_num'], ascending=[1,1]))


# Variables

A = build_rating_sparse_tensor(ratings)

U = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(
        [A_Sparse.shape[0], embeddings], stddev=init_stddev))

# this matrix would be transposed in the equation
V = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(
        [A_Sparse.shape[1], embeddings], stddev=init_stddev))


# loss function
def sparse_mean_square_error(sparse_ratings, user_embeddings, movie_embeddings):

  predictions = tf.reduce_sum(
                    tf.gather(user_embeddings, sparse_ratings.indices[:, 0]) *
                    tf.gather(movie_embeddings, sparse_ratings.indices[:, 1]),
                    axis=1)
  loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(sparse_ratings.values, predictions)
  return loss
```

Is it possible to do this with a particular loss function, optimizer and learning schedule?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How important to you is the fact that A is sparse? It is complicated to calculate gradients on sparse matrixes. You should also know that tensorflow does not support calculating gradients on integer (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20524)

Comment: @Lescurel Let's say that A is a matrix of 10.000 x 500.000. I think that for that size it has to be sparse due to performance and RAM capacity. But if I'm wrong, A doesn't have to be necessarly sparse.

Comment: No, for RAM usage, a matrix as empty as this one should definitely be sparse. But it makes the problem much more difficult. A simple training loop that calculate the gradients over U and V is quite straightforward, I can post that as an answer if you are interrested, but this solutiom cannot take advantage of the sparsity.

Answer (score 2):

A naive and straightforward approach using TensorFlow 2:

Note that rating was converted to float32. TensorFlow cannot calculate gradients over integer, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20524.

```
A = build_rating_sparse_tensor(ratings)
indices = ratings[["U_num", "V_num"]].values
embeddings = 3000

U = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([A.shape[0], embeddings]), dtype=tf.float32)
V = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([embeddings, A.shape[1]]), dtype=tf.float32)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam()

trainable_weights = [U, V]

for step in range(100):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        A_prime = tf.matmul(U, V)
        # indexing the result based on the indices of A that contain a value
        A_prime_sparse = tf.gather(
            tf.reshape(A_prime, [-1]),
            indices[:, 0] * tf.shape(A_prime)[1] + indices[:, 1],
        )
        loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(A_prime_sparse, A.values))
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, trainable_weights))
    if step % 20 == 0:
        print(f"Training loss at step {step}: {loss:.4f}")
```

We take advantage of the sparsity of A by calculating the loss only over the actual values of A. However, we still have to allocate two really big dense tensor for the trainable weights `U` and `V`. For big numbers like in your example, you will probably encounter some OOM errors.

Maybe it could be worth exploring another representation for your data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Actually, I had available a loss function (I will add it to the main post since I cannot put code in this comment). I think that it would perform better since it doesn't compute tf.matmul(U, V).